# Is it possible to pass a PHD without full understanding of ones own thesis?

Tags: thesis

This is likely to be a rather strange question.

I have been working in physics in an attempt to obtain a PHD.
My initial plan was entirely experimental, however I have not obtained enough data by itself.
This is due to a combination of difficult experiments, and temperamental equipment and its repeated failures; I was and am simply not capable of repairing the systems without any replacement components by myself.

This is ok I had thought, I can attempt to slightly extend a pre-existing theoretical framework to explain the few results that I do have.
However this is not my supervisor, or even departments expertise, so I have for the last year and half attempted this myself.
After much effort I have been able to replicate the prior theoretical calculations of the model.

However despite having the best grasp of the model out of anyone I have spoken to in my department, there are significant parts where I just do not have a clue.

I have reached a point where I have 2 months left to submit, and I do not yet have a sufficient understanding of the theory to be able to tell if it is actually valid for what I am trying to use it for.

Is it acceptable to just shut up and apply it anyway, and be deliberately vague and sparse in describing it and the necessary mathematics so that I do not include things I do not understand?

Or do I just throw in the towel and save myself another 2 months of absolute torment?

Many thanks.

Edit in response to comments:
it's rather that I do not understand some of the mathematics necessary.

There is a set of 6 eigenfunction equations, where they all have the same eigenvalues.
All the authors in the literature only care about the eigenvalues, where I need the eigenfunctions.
I had assumed that they were all the same, like the eigenvalues, but upon attempting to write a thesis chapter on them I now realise that they are not.
This is a problem as my calculations are based upon the eigenfunctions.

There is only one of the eigenfunction equations in the literature.
I am able to, with initial difficulty, solve it and obtain the same eigenvalues as the literature.
I then do some stuff with the eigenfunction that was not done, and obtain another different eigenvalue equation based upon an operator corresponding to the measuremrnt data I do have.
But I cannot derive the original equation in the literature, and I cannot derive the other, not stated in the literature, 5 equations.

Noone has worked on it for decades, and the original authors, and those who initially extended their work, are all dead.

Hence why I state that I do not understand it.
I can state what I have done, that I cannot derive the equations, and that I know it is wrong without the other 5 solutions.
I am 90% certain I can solve the other 5 equations if only I could understand how they are obtained.

Unfortunately I just get bogged down in attempting to follow the derivation, 1.5 years of attempting to follow it and I still just do not follow it.

Comment: Isn't there anyone else you can ask? 2 months is tight, you really should had done that earlier, but the world is bigger than you department

Comment: Answering the title question: No, you are very unlikely to obtain a PhD if you don't understand your own thesis. (The only chance would be if your dissertation committee failed in their duty to properly examine you.) You should try to find someone outside your department who can help. Surely people in your department can connect you with someone appropriate.

Comment: In your educational system, who actually decides whether you pass?  In many systems, it's effectively your supervisor, in which case you need to have a frank conversation with him or her.

Comment: There's "understanding", and then there's "understanding". I think it is typical that even very good PhD students have a relatively superficial understanding of the significance/context of their own work, simply and inevitably due to lack of experience. But if the question is about "ok-ness", that's more serious than "understanding" (depending on what we make these words mean, of course...)

Comment: For many complex experiments, no one, and I mean _no one_, has a full understanding of all the details.

Comment: Research builds on previous research. No researcher verifies every detail of every result that they cite (especially since to do so exhaustively, they would need to verify every detail in every source that the cited works themselves cite...). It is perfectly acceptable to e.g. invoke a known theorem in mathematics even if you haven't worked through a proof of that theorem. If the results that you are using are known results -- just cite them and move on with your life, especially if the derivation of those results are outside of the scope of your studies.

Comment: John Coleman, is it then acceptable to, as in this case, use an equation and its solutions without more than a superficial understanding?

Comment: @PlokavianNerveGas It's not ideal, but a lot of things aren't ideal. I'd say that a better understanding is usually better, but the most important things is to get it done!

And, presumably, there is a period of time after your submission but before your viva/defense? That is time that you can use to work on your understanding of the problem, if you still deem it necessary.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Of course, it would be good if someone around you can help you see what needs to be done to legitimize your use of "the other 5 equations". If you post to MathStackExchange, someone might be able to help, for example, if no one physically nearby can.

In any case, honesty and at least a nominal "dispassion" about things is the best approach, I think. Say what you assume, say what you can verify, say what previous sources say, etc. It's ok, I think, if your results are "relative" (=relative to assuming that certain sources are ok, plus assuming that certain extensions, which you've tried but failed (so far) to validate yourself first-hand, are ok...), as long as you are very clear on what your results are relative *to*.

Don't bluff... :)

Comment: Ok , so I shall be absolutely clear on what exactly the problem  I think is, and not attempt any obfuscation. This can then be good enough or not.

Answer (score 6):

> Or do I just throw in the towel and save myself another 2 months of absolute torment?

Nobody except you would be able to decide. But, given what you write, failing could be an option. Academia is a hard sport, and your health might be more important than some theory. I see bad examples around me.

In case you decide to proceed, here are some thoughts:

- Ask an online service (such as Google scholar) for ***which papers cite the  original framework***. Some of the authors referencing the framework might be living. Write them e-mails.
- Apply *Feynman's problem-solving algorithm*. (It's not a joke, I'm very serious.) In less extravagant terms, improve your working style.
- Apply for an extension.
- ...

Bear in mind that, after all, the problem might be unsolvable with the methods at your disposal.

E.g., the mature Ostrogradsky once asked Paris mathematicians for help for solving a particular problem. They took quite some time, and finally responded "This task can be solved only by one person: the Russian professor Ostrogradsky. He lives in Petersburg. You should contact him.".

But one proper piece of advice: no torment; **go home at 6pm** whatever you do.

Comment: Do you mean the famous, look at the problem and write down the solution, Feynman method?

Comment: @PlokavianNerveGas Do not skip step 2.

Comment: @JeffE I shall think as hard as is possible without shattering my fragile psyche.

Answer (score 2):

For a PhD you should demonstrate two things: that you have become an expert in your (very very small) chosen topic, and that you have learned how to do credible research in that topic. From your description you don't seem to have demonstrated either at this point, so I would find it concerning if you did get a PhD.

Kicking in the towel isn't the only option though.

- You say no-one in your department understands the material. But it is extremely unlikely that no-one in the world does. There are many theoretical physicists, and many mathematicians. Even if they are not familiar with the exact problem, there will be someone you can talk to who knows far more about eigenfunctions than you seem to.
- Get an extension. If you've been allowed to go substantially beyond the expertise of those supervising you where you don't understand and no-one else is supporting you, then someone has not really been taking their responsibilities seriously enough.
- Try and find a summer school on the mathematics you need.
- Explore the options for graduating with a lower degree.

Comment: -1 For all we know the OP is an expert in the experimental side of the matter. It seems like a series of factors + lack of anticipation from themselves and their supervisor led to this situation.

Comment: Ah, well the two months is the extension. I was also the impression that supervision was meant to be functionally nonexistent once one had a plausible research plan near the start of ones phd? Would the phd not then only indicate your supervisors research ability and ones ability to follow instruction otherwise?

Comment: @PlokavianNerveGas, I think one's advisor is meant to help!!! Otherwise, what's the point? Contrary to myths, a PhD student does not become a world expert in a few months or years, but, rather, needs some advice from experts, that is, their advisor and others.

Comment: @user347489 Yes, they may well be an expert in the experimental side. But they've written a theoretical thesis. I'm not saying it's entirely their fault, but they have still not met the requirements of a PhD.

Comment: @PlokavianNerveGas A PhD is an apprenticeship as a researcher. Your supervisor should be training you to be a researcher.

Comment: @PlokavianNerveGas https://www.findaphd.com/advice/doing/phd-supervisor-expectations.aspx

Comment: @PlokavianNerveGas No, higher education is not just providing the time and library resources. Otherwise what would the teacher be there for? There is also guiding the use of time to relevant resources, and helping with the interpretation of those resources where you get stuck. And providing a 'big picture'.

Comment: @PlokavianNerveGas To be a successful researcher, you don't just need to know about your topic. You need to know what the relevant journals and conferences are, and how to engage with them successfully. You need to meet other researchers who can work with you. You need to know the background skills for your research (in your case the mathematics of eigenfunctions). Your supervisor should have assisted you in gaining these skills, either by teaching you themselves or directing you to other resources.

Comment: Thank you for your advice.
I have made it to the end of the PhD process, and while I may have passed, I do not think that I should have; I honestly cannot say that I have skills or knowledge suitable for a PhD, and by passing I have undermined the value of all other PhD's by association.
This has had the effect of completely and utterly obliterating my faith in, trust of, and support of higher education and publically funded research.
My best hope now is that my unearned and undeserved qualifications can trick a potential employer into giving me a opportunity to avoid financial destitution.

Comment: @PlokavianNerveGas Congratulations on passing. Don't be too hard on yourself, and everyone else. It sounds like your feelings are probably largely based on just having spent many years working hard on something that didn't go well. I won't deny the possibility that you do not deserve a PhD at all, but it may be instead that your judgement of the minimum requirements/your achievementsis a bit out of line. There's a difference between 'got a PhD' and 'did well enough to continue a career in academia'. Also, even if you didn't do well, that doesn't mean no-one is achieving important results.